# Joomla 3.3.0 Installation Error

Tags: javascript, joomla, mysqli

I'm trying to install Joomla 3.3.0 on XAMPP 1.8.3 (I can't install an earlier XAMPP version, due to company restrictions). And it fails upon completing the last step. The installation loads forever during the second task, where it creates new database tables.
When I take a look at the console, it says

```
TypeError: r is null
```

on line 187 in installation.js

I tried to comment this line, which, obviously, caused another error, which I didn't look further into.

I chose MySQLi for this installation.

If you need more information on this, let me know.

Comment: why would you even use an earlier version of XAMPP?

Comment: I heard, that some folks have problems with this version due to "too high PHP versions" (5.4+). No idea what they mean specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you ever got an answer to this but I faced the same issue and this did the trick... Add between line 656 and 658, in ../libraries/joomla/session/session.php

```
session_save_path('../tmp');

ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
```